# Что означает следующтй код?

Tags: c, graphics

Доброго времени суток, наткнулся на следующий код, не совсем понимаю что он делает. Программа про пересечение прямых.

```
enum {
    TOP = 0x1,
    BOTTOM = 0x2,
    RIGHT = 0x4,
    LEFT = 0x8
 };
void cut(float x0,float y0,float x1,float y1){
int outcode0,outcode1,outcodeOut;
if(outcodeOut==outcode0){
        x0 = x;
        y0 = y;
        outcode0 = CompOutCode(x0,y0);
    }
    else{
        x1 = x;
        y1 = y;
        outcode1 = CompOutCode(x1,y1);
    }
}

int CompOutCode(float x,float y){
int code = 0;
if(y>ymax)
code|=TOP;
else
if(y<ymin)
code|=BOTTOM;
if(x>xmax)
code|=RIGHT;
else
if(x<xmin)
code|=LEFT;
return code;
```

Comment: Не натыкайтесь на код, пишите свой.

Comment: Просто интересно для чего функция СompOutCode.

Comment: Пройдитесь по каждой строке и сами поймете.

Comment: Проставляет и возвращает битовые флаги, исходя из положения точки относительно прямоугольника *(xmin, ymin) - (xmax, ymax)*.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `CompOutCode` реализует ограничение перемещения объекта в заданных границах.